# React Native Multidex with smali file

Tags: android, react-native, smali

Apk build with react native problem after enable Multidex and Dalvik problem with MainActivity with this Smali file.

```
.line 25
invoke-super {p0, p1}, Lcom/facebook/react/ReactActivity;->onCreate(Landroid/os/Bundle;)V

.line 26
invoke-static {}, Lcom/facebook/react/modules/i18nmanager/I18nUtil;->getInstance()Lcom/facebook/react/modules/i18nmanager/I18nUtil;

move-result-object v0

.line 27
.local v0, "sharedI18nUtilInstance":Lcom/facebook/react/modules/i18nmanager/I18nUtil;
invoke-virtual {p0}, Lir/androidkar/customer/MainActivity;->getApplicationContext()Landroid/content/Context;
```

what should i do in android SDK version 27?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just enable multi dex

```
android {
....
defaultConfig {
    ...
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

clean your project and build again

Comment: app Build.gradle